# Download a Graphviz DOT graph as a PNG file in streamlit

Tags: python, graphviz, streamlit

I have a graph object "graph" that is of type graphviz.Digraph(), I'm trying to write a function that takes "graph" as input and returns data that can be downloaded  using argument data in Streamlit st.download_button  ?

Here is my code:

```
import base64
import streamlit as st

def to_image(g):
    image_data = g.pipe(format='png')
    image_base64 = base64.b64encode(image_data).decode()
    return image_base64

graph_img = to_image(g=graph)
st.download_button(label="Download PNG Image",
                   data=graph_img,
                   file_name='graph.png',
                   mime='image/png')
```

This code seems to work, but resulting PNG file is not readable, where is the issue?